# Adobe AIR NetworkInfo native extension does not support AIR Simulator?

Tags: ios, flash, air

Hi I downloaded the AIR NetworkInfo native extension (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html) it works when I test it on the ipad but when I test my app on the desktop I get an error

> "The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Requested extension com.adobe.Networkinfo is not supported for MacOS-x86."

I have other extensions that do not throw this error. I'm using Flashbuilder 4.6 and when I look at the Actionscript Build Packages for Apple IOS I see a warning that the extension "Does Not Support AIR Simulator". I don't want to have remove the extension everytime I test on the desktop and shouldn't have to. Anyone have any ideas what is happeneing?

Answer (score 2):

It is because the NetworkInfo ANE is compiled for the ARM archteture, and will not run on your simulator, just on a real device. You should do a build script to avoid adding and removing each time you want a release build.